# Can I assign keyboard shortcut to the Microsoft Intellitype keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Anyone know if I can assign a keyboard shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (for closing the current tab in IE/Firefix etc) to the Microsoft Keyboard favourite keys 1-5.

I have Microsoft Keyboard software installed and I can only browse to applications I want to run and cant seem to see anywhere else where I can assign shortcuts.

Comment: Should be closed as 'notprogrammingrelated'.

Comment: Maybe, but it's the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unlock the Function button on top of the Numkey pad, then use the F6/Close key ;)

Comment: Have fun with your new SO addiction ;)

Answer (score 1):

trouble is it takes 2 button presses - was just looking for a single button press maybe using the user defined buttons 1 to 5 to quickly close tabs / windows etc.

Comment: It takes 2 buttons presses if you enabled disable it all the time, mine is not on to use the features.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way! i've done it before! Now I can't figure out how I did it. I had all the media keys configured to Control-alt-home and stuff like that to match with Winamp since the default play pause wasn't working.
But I can't figure out howI did it.

Answer (score 0):

I found something here:

http://musingsfromtheunderground.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-microsoft-natural-ergonomic.html

which uses Autohotkey to ditch the Intellitype software altogether. Autohotkey can send any kind of key presses, for example,

```
Send ^{F4}
```

will send Ctrl+F4. Any other key combination is only up to your imagination, not to mention that you can script almost anything you want with Autohotkey and assign those functions to the favourite keys.